# How to match an exact word through SPARQL

Tags: regex, sparql, jena, arq

My application needs to match the correct word i.e. say C or C++ with SPARQL. I have the following SPARQL query

```
String prolog = "PREFIX kb: <" + VBOOK.getURI() + ">";

String queryString = prolog

+ "\n"

+ "SELECT * "

+ "WHERE {?x kb:Price ?price. ?x kb:Currency ?currency. ?x kb:Title ?title. ?x kb:Count ?count. "

+ "OPTIONAL {?x kb:Description ?description}."

+ "FILTER regex(?title, \"" +title + "\")}";
```

This matches me all books even C++,C# and books like -Real Concepts in Embedded Systems (because of the word 'Concepts' having 'C').

if I change the last line to

```
+ "FILTER regex(?title, \"" +"^"+title + "\")}";
```

and if title is for example 'C' then my query matches only those books whose titles start with letter 'C'.So books like 'Programming in ANSI C' are not selected.

I have also tried with the following change in the last line

```
+ "FILTER regex(str(?title), \"" +title + "\")}";
```

Even this has not helped me much.

How do I modify to get the books pertaining to 'C' even if the books title do not start with C?

Regards,
Archana.

Comment: Duplicated on http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/3750/how-to-match-an-exact-word-through-sparql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question boils down to what regular expression features your query engine supports. If it supports `\b` word boundary matching, you can solve your problem by changing the last line to

```
 + "FILTER regex(?title, \"\\b" + title + "\\b\")}";
```

Comment: No it is not giving me any result when I am typing 'C'.

Comment: @Archana: Well, what query engine are you using?

Comment: ARQ-2.8.5 and Jena-2.6.3.I am using tomcat server i.e java server.

Comment: @Archana: ARQ uses `java.util.regex` which supports `\b`. Your problem is elsewhere. Case sensitivity perhaps? You can add a third `"i"` argument to SPARQL `regex` to make it match case insensitively.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need regex at all?

Instead of making title a variable, simply fix it so -

?x kb:Title "title" .

i.e. in your code

String title = "C++";

"WHERE {?x kb:Price ?price. ?x kb:Currency ?currency. ?x kb:Title \""+title+"\" . ?x kb:Count ?count. "

Comment: I need to try this. But for now my input if C++ is typed the program takes C so I need to figure this. I just figured this was the reason as to why C++ was not being searched. Will get back to this solution once my input is correctly taken.